# How to fix webRTC packet loss, specifically from Discord Streams?

Tags: discord, webrtc, streaming, lag, connectivity

I've been experiencing major issues with streams in the last few weeks, i.e. my (possibly whole) network connection slows down when experiencing these packet losses from a simple discord stream. (Even on other devices, hence i don't think it's malware or something alike..)

To be more specific, i debugged the discord stream itself and the only things "obvious" are the vast amount of **NACKs and packets lost**.
A look into some discord logs revealed the following info: **NACK entry removed, too many entries** or something along the lines.

It's affecting the stream quality (about 1 frame per 15s, audio seems rather fine though) and even voice chat (mostly only the person streaming?!). Other programs (games) seem fine, but the webbrowser is very slow too.
I don't experience any other issues and this problem only arrises while watching discord streams (or at least trying to).
Unfortunately, the discord support couldn't help me and neither could my ISP. Both don't seem to see an issue on their side, however I certainly have packet loss and issues network wide!

I tried the "usual" stuff: *reinstalling discord, unplugging router (even over night), flushing dns, resetting the router itself, deleting all kinds of caches, checking firewall and registry and a traceroute* with the discord support. None of these helped, it seems to be even worse now.

I've speculated that my usage of TronScript could've caused this in a stage of removing telemetry, but the logs don't confirm this. I did not change anything else, so I thought this could be it.

I am just really frustrated at this point and would love to know if anyone has more experience on this or could've any idea whatsoever to what is causing this.

Comment: I believe I have the exact same problem and that it must be network related. It occurs on any device (mac,ios,windows) when whatching streams over discord but only in my local wifi. Using a mobile 4g connection it all works as expected on the same devices. Closing and opening the stream multiple times fixes the problem for a short time. Sadly I have not found a solution for this yet. I suspect it may have something to do with the network of my local dsl provider and that I can't fix it on my side at all.